# Generate three random characters in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Hi I am trying to generate three random characters using a function in Delphi, the code is this:

```
function generate(cantidad: integer): string;
const
  letras_mi = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const
  letras_ma = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const
  numeros = '0123456789';
var
  finalr: string;
begin

  finalr := '';

  finalr := finalr + IntToStr(Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1);
  finalr := finalr + IntToStr(Random(Length(letras_ma)) + 1);
  finalr := finalr + IntToStr(Random(Length(numeros)) + 1);

  Result := finalr;

end;
```

the problem is that things like 20142 me back when I'm actually waiting 3 characters constant random variables.

Comment: Are you supposed to do something with the passed in parameter `cantidad`?

Comment: @MarcusAdams: *Cantidad* is Spanish for "quantity", so I assume that what we have here is a snippet of a larger function, in which that parameter serves as the end-point of a FOR loop.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your code is converting integer index values to strings.  Note that your only reference to your constants is to take their length. You return indices rather than characters.

You could fix your code by using the integer indices you generate to reference elements within your string constants. Mason and Ken showed how to do that.

Personally I would do away with the constants and write

```
Chr(ord('a') + Random(26))
```

and

```
Chr(ord('A') + Random(26))
```

and

```
Chr(ord('0') + Random(10))
```

The ordinal values of these characters were designed way back when to allow such code.

Comment: Very elegant solution :-) One advantage of obliterating the constants is EXE size (although not by much) but if you were to do this on a larger scale, let's say these constants are used in 50 different places, then at compile-time all those constants would be continuously duplicated - and all those characters would add up. Not that it makes too much of a difference though, probably 1kb, but still.

Comment: @JerryDodge I just do it this way because I come from the 80s and that's how I learnt it back then. It seems simpler to me to understand, and to check. Easy to miss a letter in those constants.  And the letters are all coded in character sets. I don't like duplication.

Comment: I've seen someone create a string constant with probably 1,000 characters, and use that constant in many many different places. What wasn't realized is that compilation will copy that constant to as many string literals as there are references to that constant. So for example, a 1,000 char constant used 50 times would produce 50,000 characters total.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but I have a question because I want to generate random numbers from 1 to 3 and I have this: Random (4-1) + 1, I wonder if it's okay because if I do poorly when used in a random array will give me Error

Comment: 1+Random(3) gives you random numbers chosen from 1, 2 and 3. But that's not the question that you asked.

Comment: @Jerry: Have yo verified that? IIRC the compiler/linker is smart enough to detect such duplicates. But I havent' tested it either. :-)

Comment: @JensG I suspect Jerry is right. A true constant does not have an address. By which we can infer it is pasted inline wherever it is used. I guess the compiler could optimise but I bet it does not.

Comment: I put this to a simple test, starting with an empty application, monitoring the compiled size after each code addition. Strangely, as I was adding code, the file size got *smaller* if anything. I am using XE2, and reading the file size in bytes, so that test was failed. I tested with 1 single constant with 100 characters, used hundreds of times. Again, the EXE size *shrank* instead of *grew*.

Comment: Part of that shrinking was related to the fact that I was compiling debug info, so I changed to `Release` but still confirmed there is some optimization going on, and my theory was false.

Answer (score 14):

You're adding the result of `Random` to your `finalr`, not the random letter from the constants.

Try something like this instead - it uses the return of `Random` as the index into the string constant characters:

```
function generate(cantidad: integer): string;
const
  letras_mi = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  letras_ma = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  numeros = '0123456789';
begin
  Result := '';
  Result := Result + letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1];
  Result := Result + letras_ma[Random(Length(letras_ma)) + 1];
  Result := Result + numeros[Random(Length(numeros)) + 1];
end;
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's look at what your code is doing, as a compiler sees it:

```
IntToStr(Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1)

Call IntToStr on the result of:
  Call Random on the result of:
    Add
      Length(letras_mi)
      1
```

IntToStr takes a number (such as `5`) and turns it into a string (such as `'5'`).  What you want to do is use the random value to index into your array, like so:

```
letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function RandomString(const ALength: Integer): String;
var
  i: Integer;
  LCharType: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to ALength do
  begin
    LCharType := Random(3);
    case LCharType of
      0: Result := Result + Chr(ord('a') + Random(26));
      1: Result := Result + Chr(ord('A') + Random(26));
      2: Result := Result + Chr(ord('0') + Random(10));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will generate random strings that looks like words.

```
function GenerateRandomWord(CONST Len: Integer=16; StartWithVowel: Boolean= FALSE): string;
CONST
   sVowels: string= 'AEIOUY';
   sConson: string= 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ';    
VAR
   i: Integer;
   B: Boolean;
begin
  B:= StartWithVowel;
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  for i:= 1 to len DO
   begin
    if B
    then Result[i]:= sVowels[Random(Length(sVowels)) + 1]
    else Result[i]:= sConson[Random(Length(sConson)) + 1];
    B:= NOT B;
   end;
end;
```

So, use it like this: GenerateRandomWord(3);

Answer (score 2):

```
const
Alphabetdown = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' ;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   sGeneratedAccNo : string ;

begin
    sGeneratedAccNo := sGeneratedAccNo + Alphabetdown[Random(Length(Alphabetdown) + 1)] ;
    showMessage(sGeneratedAccNo) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  function generate(cantidad: integer): string;
  const
    letras_mi = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    var i:integer;
  begin
    Result := '';
    for I := 1 to cantidad do
      Result := Result + letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1];
  end;

  function generateNum(cantidad: integer): string;
  const
    letras_mi = '0123456789';
    var i:integer;
  begin
    Result := '';
    for I := 1 to cantidad do
      Result :=  Result + letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1];
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Faster way would be avoiding re-allocation of memory time and again.

```
function generate(cantidad: integer): string;
const
  letras_mi = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  numeros = '0123456789';
begin
  SetLength(Result, 3); // only alloc memory once

  Result[1] := letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1];
  Result[2] := UpCase(letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1]);
  Result[3] := numeros[Random(Length(numeros)) + 1];
end;
```

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UpCase
- http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/upcase.html

And sometimes even slightly faster would be using local variable to avoid few extra `UniqueString` calls for var-parameter `Result`.

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UniqueString
- http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/uniquestring.html

However timings or CPU-level code check should be made for one's specific compiler version and options to see what difference this actually makes, if any.

```
function generate(cantidad: integer): string;
const
  letras_mi = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  numeros = '0123456789';
var local: string;
begin
  SetLength(local, 3); // only alloc memory once

  local[1] := letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1];
  local[2] := UpCase(letras_mi[Random(Length(letras_mi)) + 1]);
  local[3] := numeros[Random(Length(numeros)) + 1];

  Result := local;
end;
```

*PS. Ord-based approach is also better here than picking a char from array/string, but that is independent issue. Also i'd be wary to use `Chr` function with Delphi 2009 or newer, it would only work uniform on #0..#127 values. Explicitly declared typecasts like `AnsiChar(i)` and `WideChar(i)` might be more stable substitute in cause one day you would need letters outside 7-bit subrange, like eña and other European-specific ones.*

Comment: Well, faster seems not to be the issue. But faster and cleaner and simpler would be just to write it all using the `+` operator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan which makes it unexpectedly ambiguous when dealing with code for pre-Unicode Delphi (libs, legacy projects). You live in a land with Latin1 alphabet and was not bitten by those issue. However i am not sure that ella, eña and other European letters other than A..Z will have exactly the same Ord in win1250 and utf-16. // then add that expression to your answer for future novice readers

Comment: Try and concentrate on the question that was asked. We are talking about Latin letters! A..Z, a..z and 0..9. If you want to discuss other letters, then try a different question.  ;-)

Comment: I made that comments from the start. However fragile practices are not those that are broken already, but those that land mines for future program expansions. I prefer people to stay warned in advance.