# simple php code to delphi code

Tags: php, delphi, math

I would like to write that code in delphi , i have tried to do it but no luck

```
$uid = $i=0; while($i<12){ $i++;}
$uid += floor(rand() * 10);
```

which it generate a random integer like this 106128013013

how it can be done in delphi ??

i took php code from here

https://code.google.com/p/rapidleech36b/source/browse/trunk/upl/asixfiles.com_free.php?spec=svn130&r=130

// edit

this code generate only 8 digits and only last number changes

```
while i < 12 do
begin
inc(i);
end;


uid := uid + floor(random * 10);
```

i need this number for uploading files to xfilesharing pro  script like the code in the php

i found javascript code in the script it self

```
 var UID='';
    for(var i=0;i<12;i++)UID+=''+Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
```

Comment: Couldn't you have picked a source that didn't have a massive, glaring bug?

Comment: i only need the function that generate random numbers .. post edited with javascript code

Comment: The source generates **a** random number. As in a single digit. Do not use it as a reference for writing your own code.

Comment: i dont understand you, i want delphi code to give random number too same as the javescript code !

Comment: Please clarify. Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic "pseudo-code" transcription is this

```
uid = 0
i = 0
while i < 12
begin
  i = i + 1
end
uid = uid + floor(rand * 10)
```

Description of the PHP `rand` function is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Description of the `floor` function is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

To me it looks like the piece of code just calls a library function that generates random number. Delphi also has a `Rand` function - use your help file (I don't have it anymore).

Whatever is the reason why you want to write it in Delphi - there is **no hidden gem** in the referenced code worse the trouble

**EDIT:**
pseudo-code of the JavaScript code is

```
UID := ''
for i := 1 to 12
begin
  UID := UID + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
end
```

Explanation of `Math.random` is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Explanation of `Math.floor` is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Again - there is no hidden magic inside

**EDIT:**

So the code generates string of 12 random digits. Some tips on how to generate string of random characters in Delphi can be found here: [Generate three random characters in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883844/generate-three-random-characters-in-delphi)

Comment: this generate that number 43262569 and only the last number changes, it should have 12 digits .. maybe the problem in the php code .. i have edited the post above

Comment: I edited your answer to correct the syntax errors in the first block of code, but your edit overwrote it.

Comment: @JerryDodge ok, no problem, I meant the first pseudo-code as a code in pseudo language that everyone understands and colons etc. don't matter. You can edit it if you like, but I think we have already found  "transcription" that is correct enough. If you can write Delphi correctly please post an answer with final solution :)

Comment: StackOverflow social networking looks like quite a bit of fun :) I've been voted up, voted down, harshly commented and I've been wrong with my post deleted. I'm not sure yet if this is the kind of fun that I'm looking for :)

Comment: thank you , you gave me the idea and i wrote it fine in delphi now im able to use the code ;)

Comment: @Jerry, it wasn't correct. You were missing `do`, one colon and several semicolons ;-) xmojmr, currently, there is no vote on your post, but don't be surprised if there will be a downvote (not from me since I'm not voting down), but this question specifically asks for Delphi translation, so your pseudo-code or translation to some pseudo mix of Pascal with JavaScript are useless here.

Comment: @TLama, yup, I missed a bit, but at least two of those semicolons could have been excluded (although I always use them anyway)

Comment: @Tlama, this is a decent answer to a lousy question. The question doesn't actually express any problem in Delphi, so it requires no Delphi code. It seems more that it's a problem in reading PHP or JavaScript. The answer to any translation question from language X to Y is to understand what the X code does, and then write it in Y.